# Try/Catch with while loop can't work

Tags: java

**Problem**

- Method asks user for an integer value.
- Pass the value into a loop to ensure it is a positive number.
- Add a in.nextline to ensure the value don't overrun into next line of code. -
- Return integer value.

  ```
  private static int getIntFromUser(String aa) {

  int aaa = 0;
   while (true && aaa <= 0) {
       try {
           System.out.println(aa + ": ");
           aaa = in.nextInt();
               if (aaa <= 0) {
                   System.out.println("Please enter a positive number.");
               }
           } catch (Exception e) {
           System.out.println("Please enter an integer: ");

   in.next();
           }
   }
   in.next();
   return aaa;
  }
  ```

**Question**

Try/Catch with while loop can't work ?

Comment: What sorcery is this?

Comment: Fix your formatting.

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: And stop quoting your entire post. We already know that this post was made by you.

Comment: The code doesn't return the value. It doesn't end.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to use `Integer.parseInt(aa);` to see if it is an integer? If it fails, you don't need to check the whole like, just kick out of the while and throw an exception.

Comment: Also, don't use `while(true && aaa <= 0)` as it reads from left to right, so it will ALWAYS be true...

Comment: @liquidsystem That's nonsense, that's not how logical AND (whether short-cut or not) works. `while(true && aaa <= 0)` is equivalent to `while(aaa <= 0)`

Comment: Right or Left doesn't really matter in loops (except some performance, where in AND the condition coming earlier should have greatest chances of being false as compared to other conditions. While in OR, it should be opposite).

Comment: The code just get stuck and couldn't end. Any ideas why?

Comment: @liquidsystem no it wouldn't "short circuit out" (whatever that means). When aaa is assigned zero, then `while(aaa <= 0)` is true so you stay in the loop.

Comment: @L.Joe, when are you expecting it to end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested it myself, it returns aaa properly (after removing `in.next()` at the bottom of the method and replacing it with `in.nextLine()`). When you do a `return` call, you need to send it somewhere. Such as `System.out` or to a variable like `int x = getUserFromInput("test: ");`

```
public class Tester {

    private static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    private static int getIntFromUser(String aa) {

        int aaa = 0;
        while (true && aaa <= 0) {
            try {
                System.out.println(aa + ": ");
                aaa = in.nextInt();
                if (aaa <= 0) {
                    System.out.println("Please enter a positive number.");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Please enter an integer: ");
                in.next();
            }
        }
        in.nextLine();
        return aaa;
    }

    public static void main(String[] a) {
        System.out.println(getIntFromUser("test123"));
    }
}
```

**Output**

[image: Output]

Comment: The reason why I added a 'in.next(); ' is to remove the additional line character that will affect if user is prompted to enter another line.

Comment: When you do that, it required you to type it twice, instead of one time, making it useless in this case I believe. An example is if it asks your age, if you enter 13 and then enter 12, it will return 13.

Comment: Instead, you can replace that with `in.nextLine();` like your problem asks for in the original question.